# Importing data from excel files in D3 js

Tags: d3.js, excel-import

I am working on D3 js collapsible tree layout, i want to know is there any way we can directly feed the data from excel file rather than using json object file?

Comment: An Excel file has the extension .xlsx, so the answer is no. Using Excel you can save the file as CSV, and then load it using `d3.csv`. There are other JS libraries that parse xlsx spreadsheets, though.

Comment: On top of that, a tree layout uses hierarchical data... good luck encoding the hierarchical data in a CSV!

Comment: So my specific problem is there is folder present in sharepoint and i want to reflect the directory tree of that folder in d3 js collapisble tree. Any suggestions how should i proceed?

Comment: Yes: use a JSON file.

Answer (score 3):

D3.js doesn’t have built-in Excel file format parser. It does, however, have a CSV format data parser. You can save your worksheet as CSV and use the resulting text as a source for the D3.js visualization.